# I want to use deep learning to classify features to scores

Tags: artificial-intelligence, regression, deep-learning

I have a problem and was wondering if I can use deep-learning to solve it.
I have a lists of 7 features, and for each list I have 7 scores.

For examples for the features:

```
[0.2,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.1]
```

I have the following scores:

```
[100,0,123,2,14,15,2]
```

---

and for the features:

```
[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.2]
```

I have the following scores:

```
[10,10,13,22,4,135,22]
```

---

etc..

---

Any ideas of how to utilize deep learning to train a network that giving a list of features will give me back the correct scores.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic setup here for a regression problem. You could try solving this problem using a neural network toolkit. I wrote a toolkit called [theanets](http://theanets.rtfd.org) that might help, so I'll give a simple example of how you might use it:

```
import numpy as np
import theanets

# set up data arrays: X is input, Y is target output
X = np.array([
    [0.2,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.1],
    [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.1,0.2],
], 'f')
Y = np.array([
    [100,0,123,2,14,15,2],
    [10,10,13,22,4,135,22],
], 'f')

# set up a regression model:
# map from X to Y using one hidden layer.
exp = theanets.Experiment(
    theanets.Regressor,
    (X.shape[1], 100, Y.shape[1]))

# train the model using rmsprop.
exp.train([X, Y], algorithm='rmsprop')

# predict outputs for some inputs.
Yhat = exp.network.predict(X)
```

There are several options for configuring and training your model, have a look at the documentation for more info.

There are also many, many other neural network toolkits out there, here are just a few popular ones that I'm familiar with:

- [Lasagne](http://lasagne.rtfd.org)
- [Keras](http://keras.io)
- [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)

You might want to give these a try to see whether they fit better with your mental model of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

1. You generate a big number of neural networks
2. You give a fitness score to each neural net based on the results(the higher the fitness score the better)
3. You sort the neural nets by their fitness score
4. You take the first `x`%
5. You apply small mutations to each selected neural net.

Repeat 2-5 until results are satisfactory.

That big number mentioned in the first step should be roughly equal to:

```
(100/x)^generationCount
```

where the `x` here is the same one as in step 4 and `generationCount` is the amount of generations until final result.